# Проверка IP адреса трех последних цифр методом регулярных вырожений

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

написал  регулярку на проверку IP, столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Если в конце меньше 3 чисел получаю false
Буду рад выслушать любые предложения

```js
const ipAddrStingEx1 = '192.168.32.200' // или любое трехзначное число
const regEx1 = ipAddrStingEx1.match(/[1-1][9-9][2-2]\.[1-1][6-6][8-8]\.[3-3][2-2]\.[1-2][0-5][0-4]/)
console.log( regEx1 == ipAddrStingEx1) //true
    
// но если я ввожу в конце меньше 2 или 3 цифр у меня возвращает false
    
const ipAddrSting = '192.168.32.1'
const reg = ipAddrSting.match(/[1-1][9-9][2-2]\.[1-1][6-6][8-8]\.[3-3][2-2]\.[1-2][0-5][0-4]/)
console.log( reg == ipAddrSting) //false
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284147/validating-ipv4-addresses-with-regexp

Comment: Ложка дёгтя: IP-адрес не обязан быть в канонической форме.

Comment: Также будет false, если вместо 32 написать, например, 132. Или хотя бы 33. Или 166 в конце. Или что угодно в любом другом месте. Зачем у вас такая ужасная регулярка? Вам известно, для чего используются квадратные скобки ?

Comment: @Эникейщик это моя первая написанная регулярка

Comment: @Эникейщик так на то и расчет, чтобы  первые 3 части не изменялись, а только последние

Comment: Вы как-то перемудрили. [2-2] означает "2 или 2", т.е. просто 2. А просто 2 можно записать как просто 2. А ``[1-1][9-9][2-2]\.[1-1][6-6][8-8]\.[3-3][2-2]`` можно записать просто как ``192\.168\.32``.

Comment: @Эникейщик, спасибо я попробую, как быть с последней части чтоб отрабатывала от 1 - 254 . Я как понял идеальных решений нет для регулярок

Comment: а) есть, б) уж для ip-то регулярки написаны давным давно, зачем изобретать свой велосипед :)

Comment: @Эникейщик приятно ведь кататься на своем )))

Answer (score 1):

Регулярка для 192.168.32.1-255

```
let reg = /^192\.168\.32\.+(([1]|[1-9]\d?|[1]\d{2}|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])))$/
console.log(reg.test('192.168.32.1'))
```

Comment: const ipAddrSting = '192.168.32.10'
let reg = ipAddrSting.match(/^192\.168\.32\.+(([1]|[1-9]\d?|[1]\d{2}|2([0-4]\d|5[0-4])))$/)
console.log( ipAddrSting == reg) //false

Comment: Я подумал , что вам просто нужна функция которая будет при данных ip выводить true или false. Но если вам принципиально важно через match, вы можете проверять следующее  ipAddrSting !== null